# Coloring an image depending on the answers on a form

Tags: php, colors

I have got an image at the end of the form that needs to be colored depending on the answers that the user gave.

Like: There is a star and it depends what the user answer for the first question, it colors the middle of the star.

I'm using PHP.

Any ideas?

Comment: any programming language?

Comment: well, my very-very-lazy approach would be to create several stars, using several colors, if they are not too many :-)

Comment: but its not possible.. because its 10 questions and the can answer 3 different answers and depending on what the answered it colors part of the star.. so there are too many combinations.. if you get me

Answer (score 1):

Don't really need to use PHP to generate the image. You can just do it using HTML and CSS and pass the value to a JS function to mask the percentage of the star shape. [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ehsantl/sS9ug/)

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="star"></div>
   <div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thats almost what I need... let`s see if you can help me even more.. the picture I need to color it's [like this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-E_UL8FhkEV0/TcbtgNDk8OI/AAAAAAAACBA/Oq5a1Oqr6yk/s320/pentaculo+da+saude.gif) ... based on the answers of the questions.. it paints the picture...

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this use http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php
There's a lot you can draw with this library and its widely supported!

But go for Leo's answer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000787/coloring-an-image-depending-on-the-answers-on-a-form#comment35132664_23001306) to @Ehsan, you need an image like this:
[image: star image complex]

In this case instead of using PHP you could use [CANVAS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas) or [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) (the first option is better because it can be exported to image with `<canvas>.toDataURL()`).

As the CANVAS as well as SVG, are somewhat complex to understand from the beginning recommend studying the basics of one of them (a day of study must be necessary in order to understand).

I personally recommend the canvas by the following factors:

- You can export to image
- Easily integrated with javascript
- supports "2d" and "3d".
- there is little incentive on the part of developers

A great tool to start developing the "canvas" is the [Kinetic.js](http://kineticjs.com/)

Tutorials Kinetic.js:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-events-tutorials-introduction-with-kineticjs/

Tutorials html5rocks:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/search?q=canvas

## Alternatives

No need to hold to Kinetic.js, there are great alternatives:

- http://raphaeljs.com/
- http://ocanvas.org/
- http://processingjs.org/
- http://sigmajs.org/
- http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS
- http://threejs.org/